# Can't find BaseGameUtils under android-basic-samples-master. New alternatives?

Tags: android, google-play-services, basegameutils

This might seem stupid, but I spend a long time trying to find BaseGameUtils library under android-basic-samples-master. From [this download](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples), I simply cant find anything about BaseGameUtils. I am a mac user and using Android Studio. Please help, thank you!

I just found out that in a commit on Nov 29, 2017, they removed BaseGameUtils from [this download](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples). What are we using right now?

Comment: How do you know you need it?

Comment: I am using it for sign in button for google. It comes from a tutorial.

Comment: could you provide a link to the tutorial here, maybe the Utils class was created separately from the google samples code

Comment: Here is the link https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700

Comment: It's under Prepare Your IDE, under step 4

Comment: that's an old tutorial, so they might have removed it from the sample, but it was forked here: https://github.com/grantland/android-samples/tree/master/BaseGameUtils

Comment: If I am adding BaseGameUtils for my game, do I add the jar under lib under BaseGameUtils? And I am adding it as a jar dependency right?

Comment: That's right, as explained in step 5

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the current example and take things from it!